# HTML5 <audio> interrupts mobile music (Spotify,...)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I am developing a website where the landing page shows a video of waves at the beach. The customer then wanted me to implement audio in connection with that screen (some sea sounds).

---

On my way home listening to music, I checked the site from my mobile device. Everything worked great, but the music I was listening to (from Spotify, but I guess it's the same behaviour with other music apps), stopped.
I consulted Google, but didn't find a solution. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @KingRidgehead No, sorry :/

Comment: Can you provide the website link? So that I can try on my phone itself and see. I too have an iPhone and Android too.

Answer (score 0):

Your music was playing by an app in your mobile . But when you open mobile browser , and then go to the website which has a video and sound on the front page . The browser tried to run the video with music . That's why your background app , which was playing music got interrupted as browser was also trying to handle the same audio api .

The same thing happen to me on my android mobile . But the recent chrome update has fixed the issue . But mozila and other browsers are not enabling the background music till.

I have no idea about iphone .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware that it's the browser's playing of the website's sounds which is causing the background app's music to get interrupted. I'm looking for a way to still play sound effects on a website without it stopping the background music. 

…And maybe this isn't possible in most browsers, and can only be done in a few contexts, like the recent Chrome update on Android you mention.  I hope not—I'd love a more general solution!

Comment: @GeorgeWS you just answered your own question - I'm not sure it's possible right now on all browers :/

Answer (score 0):

It makes complete sense. I don't know why you would want two sounds to be playing at the same time. That would be noise I guess. I think you don't have a problem, in fact it is best the website audio pauses other audio instances on your device.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked in my iPhone with this website which has audio in it.

https://guccidive.gucci.com/

And also played song in Spotify and Gaana App. But both sounds are playing concurrently. I have iPhone 6s and used Safari browser to check.

And as Limitless Claver said it's correct only that at a time only 1 sound is playing. Since if you hear 2 sounds at the same time it will become noise for the user. And I can bet that user won't like it at all. So it's perfect to pause all other background sounds when a user is surfing your website.

There is nothing you can do for this. Since that's handled by the browser apps itself. There is nothing as of now we can do in our Website to work the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

While Windows 10 for instance allows this to happen (had two youtube tabs running with sound and another application delivering separate audio), I really question whether this is a good idea on a phone where you basically can only have one app open at any time.

It appears that Apple allows for this to happen, but its depending on the app itself, so nothing you can change for anything but your own app, AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

While HTML5 audio will be registered as music, it will take over any current music controls. However, using [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) and setting up AudioContext does not trigger this behaviour. This is the case for https://guccidive.gucci.com/ mentioned here. This site is using [Howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/) to play audio, and Howler uses the Web Audio API when available. I would recommend using Howler.